# Inheritance with abstract classes in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, annotations

I have the following situation, an article can have several types of content (e.g. Text, Images, Sourcecode, ...). Therefore I designed this simple class structure:

This is the source of the abstract **ArticleContent** class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "ARTICLE_CONTENTS" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS )
public abstract class ArticleContent extends AbstractEntity {

  private Article article;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name = "ARTICLE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false )
  public Article getArticle() {
    return article;
  }

  public void setArticle( Article article ) {
    this.article = article;
  }

  @Column( name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false )
  public abstract String getContent();

  public abstract void setContent( String content );

}
```

The `getContent()` and `setContent()` methods are marked as abstract, because they will return the content which is actually displayed (e.g. plain text, `<img src="..." />`, ...).

I started with the implementation of the **TextArticleContent** class. This class simply stores the content in a String:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "TEXT_ARTICLE_CONTENTS" )
@AttributeOverrides( { @AttributeOverride( name = "content", column = @Column( name = "CONTENT" ) ) } )
public class TextArticleContent extends ArticleContent {

  private String content;

  @Override
  public String getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  @Override
  public void setContent( String content ) {
    this.content = content;
  }
```

}

This is the error output which I receive:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException:
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.something.model.TextArticleContent column: 
  CONTENT (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Though the error messages gives me an advice what I should do (`should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"`), but honestly, as I just started using Hibernate I have no idea how to handle it.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**
The solution for this problem was that I needed to change the `@Column` annotation of the `getContent()` method. The correct annotation looks like this:

```
@Column( name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false )
public abstract String getContent();
```

I had to add **insertable** and **updatable**, which basically means that the tip in the Exception is not completely correct.

Furthermore, I needed to change the InheritanceStrategy for the abstract **ArticleContent** class.
The correct `@Inheritance` annotation is:

```
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
```

For cosmetic reasons, now the `@Table` annotation in the **TextArticleContent** class can be replaced then with:

```
@DiscriminatorValue( "TEXT_ARTICLE_CONTENT" )
```

This changes the discriminator value in the **ARTICLE_CONTENTS** table to **TEXT_ARTICLE_CONTENT**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change in ArticleContent

```
    @Column( name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false )
  public abstract String getContent();
```

to

```
        @Column( name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false,
insertable = false, updatable = false )
      public abstract String getContent();
```

**Update**.

Changed to insertable, updatable.

Comment: I could not use insert and update, had to change it to insertable and updatable. Thanks for the tip! But I retrieved the following Exception then: Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: com.something.model.TextArticleContent. Solution: I had to change the InheritanceStrategy to InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question according to your answer to help others :)